# java Need help to replace XML tag content from CSV

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to read from a csv files and replace the xml element contents with values from the CSV based on the CSV header placed between the XML tags.

toName,fromName,heading,body
John,Elvis,heading content, body content
Kahn,Elvis,heading content, body content
Jude,Elvis,heading content, body content

```
<note>
<to>{{toName}}</to>
<from>{{fromName}}</from>
<heading>{{heading}}</heading>
<body>{{body}</body>
</note>
```

Can someone please suggest how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide the structure of the record in your csv file? What is the record in your csv? A note? Have your tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can use jackson mapper to work with xml and CSV

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/tree/master/csv

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-csv</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.8</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
  <version>2.10.1</version>
</dependency>



ObjectMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
Simple value = xmlMapper.readValue("<Simple><x>1</x><y>2</y></Simple>", Simple.class);

// Schema from POJO (usually has @JsonPropertyOrder annotation)
CsvSchema schema = mapper.schemaFor(Pojo.class);

// Manually-built schema: one with type, others default to "STRING"
CsvSchema schema = CsvSchema.builder()
        .addColumn("firstName")
        .addColumn("lastName")
        .addColumn("age", CsvSchema.ColumnType.NUMBER)
        .build();

// Read schema from the first line; start with bootstrap instance
// to enable reading of schema from the first line
// NOTE: reads schema and uses it for binding
CsvSchema bootstrapSchema = CsvSchema.emptySchema().withHeader();
ObjectMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
mapper.readerFor(Pojo.class).with(bootstrapSchema).readValue(json);
```

Comment: Hi Oleg,

Thanks for the suggestion. I'll be a bit more specific with the intention of the app.
Users will select the csv data file.
Users will then copy and paste the XML in the text-area where the variables set between the xml tags will be replaced by the values from that in the csv data file.
More Info: 
First row of the csv file will be the header where it would contain columns (toName,fromName,heading,body)
First XML creation will fetch values from the Second row of the csv data file and go on until the last row in the csv data file.

Thanks